# didselectrowatindexpath textlabel return

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to return the titleField or caption value from the cell that was pressed. After a bit of digging I found some code that should work but I get the error:

> Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'titleField'

Which is also the same for all other items such as caption, tags, etc.

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"searchCell", for: indexPath)
        as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.titleField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
        cell.descriptionField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].description
        cell.tagsField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].tags
        let photoUrl = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl
        let url = URL(string: photoUrl)
        cell.SearchImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        //getting the current cell from the index path
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

        //getting the text of that cell
        let currentItem = currentCell.titleField!.text //HERE IS THE ERROR!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never use a cell to get data. Get your data from your data model just like you do in `cellForRowAt`.

And `didSelectRowAt` provides the index path of the row that was just selected.

Update your `didSelectRowAt` to something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let caption = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    let tags = posts[indexPath.row].tags
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: your are initializing the cell as UITableViewCell in the DidSelectRow method. Just change it to CustomTableViewCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // getting the current cell from the index path
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as CustomTableViewCell     // THE SOLUTION

    // getting the text of that cell
    let currentItem = currentCell.titleField!.text 
}
```

or you can use your data Array as well to retrieve the label value using the indexPath

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cast the cell in`didSelectRow` to `UITableViewCell` not `CustomTableViewCell`. Another point is that you can use the indexPath directly. There is no need for `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as CustomTableViewCell

    //getting the text of that cell
    let currentItem = currentCell.titleField!.text
}
```